# Blank Menubar in Google Chrome for 14.04

Tags: google-chrome

Just did a clean 32-bit install of 14.04.

Downloaded the 32-bit .deb of Google Chrome, and installed in the Ubuntu Software Center.

There's no menubar for Google Chrome now. Was working fine in 12.04, but now it's gone. Is this a bug? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try typeing chrome://settings into the omnibox and toggle the "Use system titles and borders" option.

Comment: No, that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hunting around for a bit, I figured this one out.

Chrome isn't actually supposed to have a menubar: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/CdCp6_6gS4Q/k2W-V_Q1gIEJ

It was a weird quirk that it actually *was* present in 12.04. I'd only been using 12.04 and Mac OS X. A menubar is present in both of those environments, but I realized that those instances were the exception.

Hope this helps anyone else who was in a similar situation, upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 and was confused.